# Is the Kraken a single being or a species?

Tags: norse, mythical-creatures

In Norse mythology, the Kraken is said to be a gigantic octopus (or sometimes a squid) that attack sailing ships. It is said that the Kraken would surface at Ragnarök.

So far, I haven't found any articles stating that the Kraken is a single entity. Nor have I found anything which denies it. Is the Kraken a single being or is it a species?

Answer (score 11):

The Kraken is a single entity. However in modern times it became a more loose term having sailors during the 1500-1700s calling giant squids "Krakens". The possibility of so many sightings led people to believe that this was a race.

The Norse mythology named the beast Kraken based on the word Krake means "a twisted animal" while Krake in German means "Octopus"

The Kraken in Norse mythology was definitely a giant squid because octopus was too far south for Norsemen to come into contact with.

Answer (score 2):

In *[Konungs Skuggsjá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konungs_skuggsj%C3%A1)* it is speculated that there are precisely two of them.

From [Laurence M. Larson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_M._Larson)'s translation, *[The King's Mirror](https://ia800300.us.archive.org/22/items/kingsmirrorspecu00konuuoft/kingsmirrorspecu00konuuoft.pdf)* P. 125:

> There is a fish not yet mentioned which it is scarcely advisable to
>   speak about on account of its size, which to most men will seem
>   incredible. There are, moreover, but very few who can tell anything
>   definite about it, inasmuch as it is rarely seen by men; for it almost
>   never approaches the shore or appears where fishermen can see it, and
>   I doubt that this sort of fish is very plentiful in the sea. In our
>   language it is usually called the "kraken." I can say nothing definite
>   as to its length in ells, for on those occasions when men have seen
>   it, it has appeared more like an island than a fish. Nor have I heard
>   that one has ever been caught or found dead. It seems likely that
>   there are but two in all the ocean and that these beget no offspring,
>   for I believe it is always the same ones that appear. Nor would it be
>   well for other fishes if they were as numerous as the other whales,
>   seeing that they are so immense and need so much food.